# Find size and number of ~nan areas of array

Tags: arrays, matlab, nan

I have the following plot:

[image]

It is based on array, where all the colored areas are ~isnan and the white areas are nan.

I have to find the number and the size(dx,dy) of each colored spot. Does somebody have a good approach to do this? My approach looks like this:

```
W_w_dy = nan(size(W_w)) ;
for ii = 1 : length(W_w(1,:)) ; % anzahl spalten
    tmp = W_w(:,ii) ;
    % logical for testing on nan
    find_nan = isnan(tmp) ;
    % indizes with not nan
    ind = find(find_nan==0) ;
    % initillisiere dy
    dy = zeros(length(W_w(:,1)),1) ;
    for jj = 1 : length(ind) ;
        tmp_down = 0 ;
        ind_tmp = ind(jj) ;
        while find_nan(ind_tmp) == 0 ;
            if ind_tmp > length(ind)
                break
            end
            tmp_down = tmp_down + 1 ;
            ind_tmp = ind(jj) + tmp_down ;
        end
        dy(ind(jj)) = tmp_down ;
    end
    clear tmp_down ind_tmp

%     for kk = 2 : length(dy) ;
%         if dy(kk-1) > dy(kk)
%             dy(kk) = 0 ;
%         end
%     end
    W_w_dy(:,ii) = dy ;
    clear dy find_nan tmp ind dy_neu
end
```

The array the plot is based on is W_w. My idea is to go through each column and get an array, where for each cell is written who many cells below are ~isnan.

This can be done for each line, too. But I do not really have an idea how I can count the eddies and get each eddie one dx and one dy.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Do you have the image processing toolbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the solution for the Problem now.

```
find_nan = ~isnan(W_w) ;

stat = regionprops(find_nan,'Centroid','BoundingBox') ;
```

lookfor the function `regionprops()`

Here is the link to the Mathworks awnser:

https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/351569-find-size-and-number-of-nan-areas-of-array?s_tid=email_ans_new_ans_ans_h#answer_276804